# (Adobe LiveCycle) Dynamic Table Header columns widths repeat wrong on multiple pages

Tags: adobe, livecycle, adobe-form

i have a dynamic table which some columns are hide or visible depending on the data.

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZd1F.jpg)

no data case:
[no data case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5oQE.jpg)

visible columns when data binding:
[visible case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7new.jpg)

i writed a script control columnsWidths and it work perfectly on page 1, but when data flow more than 1 page the header not appear as the same as page 1.

my code:
var vendor = SMF001.SMF001_Form.subfrmTableBlock.TableBlock.gprHeader.HeaderRow.txtVendor.rawValue;

if ( vendor == null or vendor == "" or vendor == "hidden" ) then
  TableBlock.columnWidths = "27.646mm 23.828mm 20.739mm 36.375mm 22.645mm 26.646mm 26.006mm 23.464mm";
else
  TableBlock.columnWidths = "27.646mm 23.828mm 20.739mm 24.375mm 19.645mm 23.646mm 22.006mm 23.464mm";
endif

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1uqp.jpg)

it seem like the code hide/unhide columns still work but something happend with columns width.

can anyone tell me what im i missing here ?

i tried another approach, create another subform and move only table header into this, change table subform to Overflow Leader.

[create overflow subform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFQcx.jpg)

In this way the code worked on page 2 but only work when overflowLeader subform is below table subform and some random text appear on page 2.

[random text error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrtHT.jpg)